# Embedding Contextual Object Icon using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm somewhat inexperienced with VBA coding and need help inserting an object into an Excel spreadsheet based on a cell reference.

What I need to be able to do is pull a PDF in as an object icon based on another cell's contents, overlay it over a specific cell and then move down a row to repeat indefinitely until a blank cell occurs.
One problem with this is that the item number in column A may not have a corresponding file that matches it in my file directory, so I need for the code to run regardless of an error in the search for the PDF. Here's an example of the layout of my sheet.  [Spreadsheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nBH7.png)

Here's the small bit of code that I have cobbled together already, however I'm not confident that it's even remotely usable.

```
Dim varItem
Sub Insert_PDF_Object()

    Range("A2").Select    

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        varItem= ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).RowHeight = 80
        Get_Object
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    Range("A3").Select

End Sub

Sub Get_Object()

        Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add Filename:="c:\Test\"& 
            Range("A2").Value & ".pdf", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, 
            Left:=40, Top:=40, Width:=100, Height:=100
End Sub
```

Any help anyone can provide would really be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Note if you want to use `DisplayAsIcon:=True` then you need to supply the path to the icon file and the index.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/oleobjects-add-method-excel

```
Sub Insert_PDF_Object()
    Dim c As Range, fName
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")

    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0

        fName = "c:\_Stuff\Test\" & c.Value & ".pdf"

        If Dir(fName, vbNormal) <> "" Then
            c.RowHeight = 80
            c.Worksheet.OLEObjects.Add Filename:=fName, Link:=False, _
                DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
                Left:=c.Offset(0, 1).Left, _
                Top:=c.Offset(0, 1).Top, _
                Width:=80, Height:=80
        End If

        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, this worked quite well! Thank you so much! My only issue is then getting the icon to display. I thought that if I was embedding it as I would an object through the insert tab, it would just display the Adobe PDF icon. Is there a way to have it just default to a standard icon? Or define the icon for all of the objects that are being embedded? Also, I'm assuming that if I want to change the offset of where it overlays the icon, I just need to adjust the Offset argument?

Comment: If you record a macro while inserting a file it will give you the type of parameters you need to supply: they are file-type-specific, but you could maybe substitute a generic icon for all files.  Yes, the Offset controls the placement -in this case a zero offset for row and one column over to the right.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much Tim this is exactly what I needed.